# How to disable links completely using hyperref package?

Tags: hyperref

A have a LaTeX paper I want to submit to the [EDAS](http://www.edas.info) system. EDAS [doesn't want papers to have links](http://edas.info/faq221) and suggests to '*remove the hyperref package from your file*'. However, if I do that, my compilation breaks because of some hyperref options in my tex files (and also \url definitions, I think).

**I want to keep everything as it is, and just disable the linking feature of hyperref to create a link-free version of my PDF. How can I do this?**

Following the [hyperref documentation](http://www.tug.org/applications/hyperref/manual.html#x1-50003.1) I did `\usepackage[draft]{hyperref}`, and that seems to work. But that doesn't seem to be the official way. And I don't want to test multiple times if EDAS accepts it or not, because all authors get notified each time I submit a new version. Also, the [draft] option doesn't remove the PDF bookmarks either, which EDAS also doesn't want.

Comment: What do you mean by 'doesn't seem to be the official way'?

Comment: @Ian: I would expect there to be an option like `\usepackage[disablelinks]{hyperref}` or similar, but I scanned the documentation and didn't find such a thing.

Comment: Did you try `\usepackage[options]{nohyperref}`? This should be a package that defines everything `hyperref` does, but does nothing.

Comment: @egreg: good suggestion, but compilation still fails on the `\url{http://...}` entries in my bibtex file (.bbl): `undefined control sequence`

Comment: Then add `\usepackage{url}`

Comment: @Rabarberski As Boris says: `\hyperref` actually loads `url`, but `nohyperref` doesn't. :(

Comment: `nohypreref` does not seem to accept `[pdftex,unicode]` as options.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Thanks to @egreg, the recipe is

```
\usepackage[options]{nohyperref}  % This makes hyperref commands do nothing without errors
\usepackage{url}  % This makes \url work
```

Comment: The `url` package does not provide the same `\url`. In particular if your URL contains special characters such as `_%#{}`, `hyperref`'s `\url` does require you to escape them with a backslash, while, with `url`'s `\url`, those characters are not to be escaped. In fact with the `url` package any `\\` in your URLs is treated as a normal character and displayed in the final PDF.

Comment: This does not work with the xr package; external references include text and numbers instead of just the equation number. Also, the pdfauthor and pdftitle options to hyperref are not accepted in nohyperref.

Answer (score 31):

Add the `draft` option to your `\hypersetup`:

```
\hypersetup{draft}
```

or as you already mentioned:

```
\usepackage[draft]{hyperref}
```

Comment: Dear downvoter, please explain why you've downvoted this answer, otherwise I'll never know what I did wrong.

Comment: FWIW, I didn't down vote, but I suspect the reason for the votes is that the OP mentions exactly this solution in his question, and also that it didn't work for him.

Answer (score 24):

`hyperref` itself provides the `NoHyper` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\begin{NoHyper}
...
\end{NoHyper}
\end{document}
```

This still creates bookmarks (listed in the "Bookmarks" navigation panel of PDF viewers). If these shall be suppressed too, add option `bookmarks=false`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[bookmarks=false]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\begin{NoHyper}
...
\end{NoHyper}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I think it is sometimes better than `nohyperref` package. `nohyperref` is too low-level to have `\url`, `\autoref` etc.

Comment: Yes, I remember that when I tried using `nohyperref`, other things went broken.

Comment: Or `\AtBeginDocument{\NoHyper}` for template authors.

Comment: While this will leave the bookmarks navigation, all the chapters in that panel seem to start on page 1.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem, however using `\usepackage[options]{nohyperref}` doesn't compile my `\autoref` links. So I used the `\usepackage[draft]{hyperref}` that you already mentioned and uploaded to the EDAS website, which seems to have accepted the entry. So using the `[draft]` option is a viable solution to part of the problem.