# How to prevent hyperref package from changing layout (line spacing)?

Tags: hyperref, line-spacing

I have a boolean in my LaTeX paper that I use to create a custom author version (including a copyright box and clickable links and references). For the author version, I include the `\hyperref` package (in the other case, I use `\nohyperref`, following my earlier question https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/53316/2090).

However, I noticed that, when including `hyperref`, my layout changes slightly (I blame it on line spacing, but not 100% sure) with the end result that the last lines of my paper get pushed to a new page.

Is there any way to NOT have hyperref influence the layout (line spacing)? Or counteract upon it in an easy way?

The hyperref options I am currently using are below. But even disabling these gives the same result.

```
\hypersetup{
    pdfborder={0 0 0},
    colorlinks=true, linkcolor=blue, urlcolor=blue, citecolor=blue,
    pdfpagemode=UseNone}
```

Comment: I suspect this may be because hyperref does not like having breaks in the middle of links. This would change the position of line breaks and hence the layout. You could try using breakurl, but I find that this does not always work.

Comment: @CPLB: I initially though this to be the reason as well. However, already on the 2nd page of my paper a shift of 2 lines to the 3rd page occur; and I don't have any URLs (http://... or similar)  at that point in the paper.

Comment: I just found your question by searching to solve a similar problem. On my side, there are discrepancies between a run with the pdftex package option (with pdflatex) and the ps2pdf package option (compiled with latex->dvips->ps2pdf). Did you find a solution ?

Comment: I ran across another question that may help you toward a solution [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/124986/hyperref-adds-vertical-space-to-listings).  Essentially, hyperref necessarily changes the formatting in order to add anchors.  In some situations, you can avoid this, but it always seems to be a pain.

Comment: @Adam: I worked around it by using inserting `\linespread{0.99}` for my custom author version

Answer (score 1):

Just reporting the workaround I eventually used.
I inserted the command `\linespread{0.99}` where applicable.

```
\ifthenelse{\boolean{AuthorVersion}}{
    \linespread{0.99}       % apparently hyperref changes layout for this paper, so adjust slightly
    \usepackage{hyperref}   % for hyper references of citations, sections, etc.
    ...
 }{
    \linespread{0.99}       % do here also, to have same layout in camready and author version
    \usepackage{nohyperref} % to disable links (EDAS doesn't want them)
    \usepackage{url}        % hyperref includes \url but nohyperref doesn't 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The draft options of `hyperref` or package `nohyperref` also removes the specials for the hyper features as links and destinations. These specials can have influence on paragraph and page breaking.

The following example disables most hyper features, when driver `pdftex` is used. Links and destinations removed by redefining the primitives of pdfTeX relying on the way, they are called in `hyperref`. The replacement definition will add a whatsit, a write whatsit to the log file, to keep the influence on the paragraph and page breaking.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex

% Disable information and catalog entries
\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \let\PDF@SetupDoc\relax
}
\makeatother

% Disable links, hyperref usually ends \pdfstartlinks arguments with \relax
\protected\def\pdfstartlink#1\relax{%
  \immediate\write-1{- \string\pdfstartlink#1}%
}
\protected\def\pdfendlink{%
  \immediate\write-1{- \string\pdfendlink}%
}

% Disable destinations, \pdfdest usually ended by \relax in hyperref
\protected\def\pdfdest#1\relax{%
  \immediate\write-1{- \string\pdfdest#1}%
}

\usepackage[
  % disable features independent from typesetting
  bookmarks=false,
  pdfpagelabels=false,
]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{Hello World}
\index{Einstein}
\begin{equation}
  \label{eq:einstein}
  E=mc^2
\end{equation}
See equation (\ref{eq:einstein}) on page \pageref{eq:einstein}.

\section{TeX user groups}
\begin{itemize}
\item[\href{http://www.tug.org/}{TUG}:] \url{http://www.tug.org/}
\item[\href{http://www.dante.de/}{DANTE}:] \url{http://www.dante.de/}
\end{itemize}

\printindex
\end{document}
```

The list of disabled features is not complete, e.g., forms and option `ocgcolorlinks` still leave traces.

The log file contains:

```
- \pdfdestname{Doc-Start}XYZ
- \pdfdestname{section*.1}XYZ
- \pdfstartlinkattr{/Border[0 0 1]/H/I/C[1 0 0]}goto name{section.1}
- \pdfendlink
- \pdfstartlinkattr{/Border[0 0 1]/H/I/C[1 0 0]}goto name{section.2}
- \pdfendlink
- \pdfdestname{section.1}XYZ
- \pdfdestname{equation.1.1}XYZ
- \pdfdestname{equation.1.1}XYZ
- \pdfdestname{equation.1.1}XYZ
- \pdfdestname{equation.1.1}XYZ
- \pdfstartlinkattr{/Border[0 0 1]/H/I/C[1 0 0]}goto name{equation.1.1}
- \pdfendlink
- \pdfstartlinkattr{/Border[0 0 1]/H/I/C[1 0 0]}goto name{equation.1.1}
- \pdfendlink
- \pdfdestname{section.2}XYZ
- \pdfstartlinkattr{/Border[0 0 1]/H/I/C[0 1 1]}user{/Subtype/Link/A<</Type/Act
- \pdfendlink
- \pdfstartlinkattr{/Border[0 0 1]/H/I/C[0 1 1]}user{/Subtype/Link/A<</Type/Act
- \pdfendlink
- \pdfstartlinkattr{/Border[0 0 1]/H/I/C[0 1 1]}user{/Subtype/Link/A<</Type/Act
- \pdfendlink
- \pdfstartlinkattr{/Border[0 0 1]/H/I/C[0 1 1]}user{/Subtype/Link/A<</Type/Act
- \pdfendlink
- \pdfdestname{page.1}XYZ
- \pdfdestname{section*.2}XYZ
- \pdfstartlinkattr{/Border[0 0 1]/H/I/C[1 0 0]}goto name{page.1}
- \pdfendlink
- \pdfdestname{page.2}XYZ
```

Does this help with your document?

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar problem which was not caused by a change in line spacing. The hyperref package was changing the paper size from A4 format to US letter format, thus leading to a page 18mm less high and shifting some text to the next page.
I fixed the problem by declaring the page size in the document class:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{letter}
```

Another solution is to declare the paper height to the desired value (for example A4 -> 297mm):

```
\setlength{\paperheight}{some value}
```